# Firestore query not working even after adding index

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data in descending order based on an int field - `value` from collectiongroup `record` where it has a particular id field. For that I've made a collectiongroup query like this :

```
  yield*
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('record')
        .where(ConstStrings.teamId, isEqualTo: team.uid)
        .orderBy(ConstStrings.value, descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map(
          (snapshot) => right<Failure, List<Record>>(
            snapshot.docs
                .map((doc) => RecordDto.fromFirestore(doc).toDomain())
                .toList(),
          ),
        )
        .onErrorReturnWith((e) {
      if (e is PlatformException &&
          e.message.contains('PERMISSION_DENIED')) {
        return left(const RecordFailure.insufficientPermission());
      } else {
        return left(const RecordFailure.unknownError());
      }
    });
```

I've added composite index for this query, which is like this :

`record`(Collection ID) `teamId Ascending value Descending`(Fields indexed)
`Collection group`(Query scope)

The query shows expected list if I remove `orderBy`, but it shows empty list if I keep that `orderBy`. Whats actually wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't have been `.orderBy("value", descending: true)` instead of .orderBy(ConstStrings.value, descending: true)? Guessing from index it the field name is  just "value"....